# Help with baml to xaml conversion?

Tags: decompilation

i have used iLSpy to decompile a .NET EXE file after the process is completed. i copied the content of xaml files from iLSpy one by one, saved the as unicode files and replaced the baml files in Visual studio project.
With the binary files (baml) the program run perfectly
With the new replaced xaml files there are many compiler errors.

Where is the error exactly?

**Note:** the errors are related to xaml design.
all references are correct.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you replaced the baml files in your project with the xaml? I doubt that can work as your app probably expects the binary format of the xaml not directly the xaml. Also try adding more detail by providing us a sample of the compiler errors you're getting.

Comment: What is the Compiler error message(s)?